# Cannot display correctly elements in an HTML document

Tags: html, css, inline

I just built a simple rock, paper, scissors game, using some javascript and html and, although the game works fine, I did't position the html elements properly apparently, as when I reduce the browser window, the objects don't stay inline. Any suggestion on how to make it so that the page can shrink without breaking lines. As you'll probably be able to tell from my code, I'm a beginner so any kind of advice is well accepted :). Sorry if this is not clear enough but this is not my first language.

this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css per carta sasso forbice.css"/>
<script> 
    var userChoice;

    function game()
    {  
        var computerChoice=Math.random();

        if (computerChoice <= 0.33){
            computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if (computerChoice <= 0.66){
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice="scissors";
        }
        var winner = function (choice1,choice2)
        {
            if( choice1 === choice2 ) {
                return "It's a tie!";
            } else if(choice1 === "rock" ){
                if ( choice2 === "paper" ){
                     return "paper wins!";
                } else if( choice2 === "scissors" ){
                    return "rock wins!";
                }
            } else if( choice1 === "paper" ){
                if( choice2 === "rock" ) {
                    return "paper wins!";
                } else if ( choice2 === "scissors" ){
                    return "scissors win!";
                }
            }else if ( choice1 === "scissors" ){
                if ( choice2 === "rock" ){
                    return "rock wins!";
                }else if( choice2 === "paper" ){
                    return "scissors win!";
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You: "+userChoice+" "+"<br>"+"Computer: "+computerChoice+"<br>"+ winner(userChoice,computerChoice);
    };    
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>ROCK, PAPER OR SCISSORS...<br><span>CHOOSE WISELY...</span></h1>
    <div class="flame"></div>
    <div class="flame"></div>
    <div class="flame"></div>
    <div id="objects">
        <div class="object" id="paper"><a onclick="userChoice='paper';game()"><img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/sheet-paper-clipart-free-vector-blank-white-paper-cartoon-clip-art_114492_Blank_White_Paper_Cartoon_clip_art_medium.png"/></a></div>
        <div class="object" id="rock"><a onclick="userChoice='rock';game()"><img src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/12/22/00/03/rock-576669_640.png"/></a></div>
        <div class="object" id="scissors"><a onclick="userChoice='scissors';game()"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT8/okg/dT8okg6Te.png"/></a></div>
    </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

this instead is the CSS code I used:

```
h1
{
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:impact;
}
#demo
{
    margin-top:-70px;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:impact;
}
h1>span
{
    font-size: 60px;
}
.flame
{
    height:400px; 
    display:inline;
    content:url("http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/093/0/7/flame_vector_by_atcen-d2ssgzi.png");
    width:30%;
    padding-left:30px;
    position:relative;
}
img
{
    height:150px;
    width:250px;
}
#objects
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-230px;
    height:300px;
}
.object
{
    width:33%;
    display:inline;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:90px;
}
#rock
{
    padding:60px;
}
#scissors
{
    padding:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you need a wrapper to include your html elements so you can control the width and their positions without breaking lines.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
<!-- Your code -->
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nmf7sp2w/1/)

```js
var userChoice;

function game() {
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.66) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    var winner = function (choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 === choice2) {
            return "It's a tie!";
        } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice2 === "paper") {
                return "paper wins!";
            } else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "rock wins!";
            }
        } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins!";
            } else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "scissors win!";
            }
        } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "rock wins!";
            } else if (choice2 === "paper") {
                return "scissors win!";
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You: " + userChoice + " " + "<br>" + "Computer: " + computerChoice + "<br>" + winner(userChoice, computerChoice);
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:impact;
}
#demo {
    margin-top:-70px;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:impact;
}
h1>span {
    font-size: 60px;
}
.flame {
    height:400px;
    display:inline;
    content:url("http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/093/0/7/flame_vector_by_atcen-d2ssgzi.png");
    width:30%;
    padding-left:30px;
    position:relative;
}
img {
    height:150px;
    width:250px;
}
#objects {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-230px;
    height:300px;
}
.object {
    width:33%;
    display:inline;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:90px;
}
#rock {
    padding:60px;
}
#scissors {
    padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>ROCK, PAPER OR SCISSORS...<br/><span>CHOOSE WISELY...</span></h1>

    <div class="flame"></div>
    <div class="flame"></div>
    <div class="flame"></div>
    <div id="objects">
        <div class="object" id="paper"><a onclick="userChoice='paper';game()"><img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/sheet-paper-clipart-free-vector-blank-white-paper-cartoon-clip-art_114492_Blank_White_Paper_Cartoon_clip_art_medium.png"/></a>

        </div>
        <div class="object" id="rock"><a onclick="userChoice='rock';game()"><img src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/12/22/00/03/rock-576669_640.png"/></a>

        </div>
        <div class="object" id="scissors"><a onclick="userChoice='scissors';game()"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT8/okg/dT8okg6Te.png"/></a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```